# Rails and SQL straight request

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails we have Model.find(id_number) request. What I want to ask is there any possibility to create straight request to DB, for example: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1` and replace rails basic `Model.where(id: 1)`?

**EDIT**

In my model.rb I have:

```
scope :search_import, -> {includes(:translations)}
default_scope -> {self.search_import}
```

And request (in rails console) looks like:

```
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
User::Translation Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users_translations`.* FROM `users_translations` WHERE `users_translations`.`category_id` IN (1)
```

But I don't want to `User::Translation` was executed (with unscoped I have the same result)

Comment: why would you want it bypassing AR?

Comment: In project on what I working on, when you do `User.find(1)` it do not just `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1`. It do some additional request with this to make sure that record is uniq, and I can't change it for all the project (cause it possibly can break logic of the models). So only for one case I need straight request to select what I need.

Comment: @AndreyDrozdov is that logic a `scope`? in that case you could do like `User.unscoped.find(1)`

Comment: I even didn't knew it) Let me try)

Comment: @Ursus, yes I have `default_scope -> self.search` and the `scope :search_import, -> includes(:method)`. I've tried to unscoped but it still have full request, mb I done something wrong? I did `User.unscoped.friendly.find(self.attributes[list.slug.to_sym]).id)` (I just need to save id)

Comment: @Ursus, I in love what you propose to solve my issue. Can you give me little more information?

Comment: Hey @AndreyDrozdov I did not understand what issue you have, I'm sorry

Comment: Ok, you're using unscoped, but if you request `.translations` or something somewhere that query is executed, you know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132016/discussion-between-ursus-and-andrey-drozdov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, something like

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1")
```

Comment: And it returns me hash, but I don't see any record information, for example in this case I want to pull name from this request above